# Passing a pointer to an array of arrays of chars to a function?

Tags: c

For the assignment I am working on, I am required to use functions to manipulate data in an array of strings. So really, an array of arrays of chars. I define the array like so:

```
char strings[5][100];
```

So there are presumably 500 contiguous chars in memory. The function I have defined looks like this:

```
void foo(char *labels[100]);
```

I think I might have some syntax issues here, but what I think this is doing is saying, "I'm a function that expects a pointer to an array of 100 chars." So `labels*` would point to the first array of chars, and `(labels + 1)*` would point to the second, and so on. I am calling the function like this:

```
foo(&strings[0]);
```

What I think this is doing is grabbing the address of the first array of chars in `strings`. The error message I'm getting tells me the function expects `char **` but the argument is `char (*)[100]`. This is confusing to me as nowhere did I specify that there be a pointer to a pointer of a `char`.

Any help is greatly appreciated, or if you could `pointer` me in the right direction `:)`

Comment: In most contexts, including function arguments, `&strings[0]` is exactly the same as plain `strings`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strings` is a two dimensional array. So it decays to `char(*)[100]` when passed to a function. Instead you can have the prototype like -

```
void foo(char labels[][100], int row); // `row` decides which param to access.

void foo(char labels[][100], int row)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) // If you need, modify all the 100 row elements
    {
        labels[row][i] = 'a'; // Modifying like this
        // ....
    }
}
```

Comment: You can then also just call it as `foo(strings, row)`;

Comment: -1 `strings` decays to a pointer to its 1st element. Its first element is of type `char[100]`, so `strings` decays to a value of type `char (*)[100]`; not `char**`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the error. If I modify values in the function, will they still be modified from where I called it?

Comment: @Brian Roach- Forgot to mention that. How ever, passing `row` value should be from 0 to 4, if `strings` has 5 rows.

Comment: @pmg - If its a two dimensional array, it decays to `char**` which definitely explains the error. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @Mahesh: the parameter in the prototype (`char *labels[100]`) decays into a value of type `char **`. The `strings` decays to a value of type `char (*)[100]` **as mentioned in the error**.

Comment: @pmg- To much coding today and how stupid my mistake is. Probably should go and take a coffee. Signing off for the day. BTW, corrected the mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Got it working in my program doing what it's supposed to do, thanks a lot everyone for the prompt and helpful responses!

Answer (score 4):

```
char strings[5][100]
```

declares `strings` as an array with 5 elements. Each element is an array of 100 chars.

```
void foo(char *labels[100]);
```

declares `foo` as a function that returns void and accepts an array of pointers. (*the 100 is merely decorative*: leaving it blank or putting 42 or 10000 is the exact same thing)

You want

```
void foo(char (*labels)[100]);
```

where the parameter is a pointer to arrays of exactly 100 chars.